# Python duckduckgo library not installing

Tags: python, module, python-import, duckduckgo-api

I'm trying to install the [duckduckgo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/1.0) for Python 3.6 (Windows), but cannot figure out how.

I first tried

```
pip install duckduckgo
```

Which raises the exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named urllib2`

Then I tried installing by downloading the tar.gz file that is located on their webpage.

I navigated to the correct directory and executed

```
python setup.py install
```

Which, apparently, ran successfully.

However, when I execute a Python script with the following code:

```
import duckduckgo
```

It raises a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like this module was never updated to support Python 3. `urllib2` is a Python 2 module and in Python3, it is simply `urllib`.

Comment: Someone apparently wrote a Python 3 version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/1.0). However, you should probably do some digging around to see if there is anything more official and widely used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE (July 2018).  This is version, duckduckpy, supports Python 3. https://github.com/ivankliuk/duckduckpy

`pip install duckduckpy`

Happy searching!